# Why use/repeat this phrase in the mishna?

Tags: maseches-keilim, maseches-parah

In eight mishnayyot ([Keilim 8:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h61.htm), [Parah 8:2–7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h64.htm), [Tahorot 8:7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h65.htm)), we find the following odd phrase.

> הרי זה אומר מטמאיך לא טימאוני ואתה טימאתני
>
> It says: that which made you *tamei* didn't make me *tamei*, but you are making me *tamei*!? [translation mine]

They all describe a situation in which A makes B *tamei* but cannot make C *tamei*, but B can make C *tamei* (and does, once B is *tamei*). This is surprising, hence (perhaps) worthy of remark.

However, does it need to be remarked upon (with the same language) nine times (and a further three in the tosefta) (and in fact several times in a row in Parah)? This personification language is unusual in the mishna (it seems to me), so why use it here? Is it simply a mnemonic/a common expression, or does it come to add something in particular to the halacha?

Comment: whenever I see the same phase repeated many times in mishnayos, my first assumption is that it's a mnemonic to help remember them.

Comment: Frankly, I remember that phrase from when I learned seder taharos and that was  some time ago. It served its purpose.